# Adding Param to Object in IE7 not working

Tags: javascript, object, param

Honestly, I'm stumped, I haven't been able to find an answer yet.

I am trying to add a param to an existing object embed via javascript, and it works every where but IE7.
Here's my code:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf" width="480" height="360" id="flashVideo">
      <param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
      <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```

and then the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var posterEncode = encodeURIComponent("images/poster.jpg");
    var fileEncode = encodeURIComponent("videos/myVideo");
    var myObject = document.getElementById("flashVideo");
    var param = document.createElement("param");
    param.setAttribute('name', 'flashVars');
    param.setAttribute('value', 'controlbar=over&amp;image='+posterEncode+'&amp;file='+fileEncode+'.mp4');
    myObject.appendChild(param);
</script>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: IE7?  Do you *really* need to use IE7?  I'm so sorry :(

Comment: What isn't working?  I know IE7's console is crap, but does it give you a message (or at least a line number)?

Comment: unfortunately... I know. but we still have some clients that refuse to upgrade. if it were up to me, I would cut them loose, but I don't run the company... I just work here.

Comment: that's just it. I'm not getting ANY errors, it's just not executing the javascript.

Comment: Have you looked into https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: I'm using camendesign.com's Video for Everybody. We have the script implemented in other assets of the site.

Comment: setAttribute isn't supported by IE until 9.0 - [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Comment: @adamdc78: well that makes sense why it's not working.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: I just implemented SWFObject, and even thought the video loads fine when it uses the HTML5 video, IE7 using the SWFObject tells me that the video file does NOT exist or does not have permission.

Comment: That's strange... I'm not sure why it'd be saying that.

Comment: interesting that when I plug in the FULL URL, works perfectly.